# Filter by cardinality-many field that contains ALL the values

Tags: clojure, datomic

I’ve got an account model that has interests, which is an array of strings (db.type=string and cardinality=many). For example:

```
{:id 42
 :name "Test"
 :interests ["cars" "games" "etc"]
 :age 50}
```

Then another list of interests come from the request. How can I query accounts what have ALL the specified interests?

For example, for `["cars" "games"]` I'll get the account #42 since it includes the passed list. But for `["cars" "games" "books"]` I won't because `"books"` is an extra one.

**UPD**

What I have is:

```
;; model
{:db/ident       :account/interests
 :db/valueType   :db.type/string
 :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/many
 :db/index       true}

;; a query
[:find ?id
 :id $ [?interest ...]
 :where
 [?a :account/interests ?interest]
 [?a :account/id        ?id]]
```

So how should I build a Datomic query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find entities whose ref-to-many attribute contains all elements of input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43784258/find-entities-whose-ref-to-many-attribute-contains-all-elements-of-input)

Answer (score 1):

Try using entities in a query

```
(d/q '[:find ?e
       :in $ ?interests
       :where
       [?e :interests _]
       [(datomic.api/entity $ ?e) ?ent]
       [(:interests ?ent) ?ent_interests]
       [(subset? ?interests ?ent_interests)]]
     (d/db conn)
     #{"cars" "games"})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(time (d/q

   '[:find ?id
     :in $
     :where

     [?a :account/interests "foo"]
     [?a :account/interests "bar"]
     [?a :account/id ?id]]

   (d/db conn)))
```

"Elapsed time: 3.771973 msecs"

```
(time (d/q

   '[:find ?id
     :in $ ?iii
     :where

     [(datomic.api/entity $ ?a) ?e]
     [(:account/interests ?e) ?interests]
     [(clojure.set/superset? ?interests ?iii)]
     [?a :account/id ?id]]

   (d/db conn)
   #{"50 Cent" "Целоваться"}))
```

"Elapsed time: 169.767354 msecs"

The first one is better.