# Datalog: Find entity pairs that have an exact match on a collection

Tags: datomic, datalog, xtdb

IF I have the following set of entities in my xtdb/datomic database

```
{:name "1" :likes [:a :b :c]}
{:name "2" :likes [:a :b]}
{:name "3" :likes [:a :b :c]}
```

I want to write a query that returns pairs of entites that have exact match on `:likes` attribute. In this case `#{[1,3]}`

There was a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43784258/find-entities-whose-ref-to-many-attribute-contains-all-elements-of-input/43808266#43808266) but in that case it doesn't care about "exact" match